# why flutter often occur return connection closed before full header was received

Tags: flutter

I use `HTTP` for connection to API, and  I have tried some flutter sdk like `2.5, 2.10.5, 3` but still have same issue often occur return `connection closed before full header was received`. and it's can occur in random api and all apps I build in flutter.

it's example of my code

```
Future<dynamic> getGoodSolution() async {
    final url = Uri.parse('$url');
    final headers = {HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json', HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Bearer mytoken123'};
    var map = <String, dynamic>{};
    map["xxx"] = "123";
    // print(headers);

    try {
      final response = await client.post(url, headers: headers, body: json.encode(map));
      final data = xxxFromJson(response.body);
      return data;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by using the `send()` method of the HTTP [(More info)](https://pub.dev/packages/http) package

```
Future<dynamic> getGoodSolution() async {
  final url = Uri.parse('$url');
  final headers = {HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json',HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Bearer mytoken123'};
  var map = <String, dynamic>{};
  map["xxx"] = "123";

  try {
    var request = http.Request('POST', url);

    request.headers.addAll(headers);
    request.body = json.encode(map);

    var streamedResponse = await request.send();
    var response = await http.Response.fromStream(streamedResponse);

    final data = xxxFromJson(response.body);
    return data;
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
    return null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an [issue ongoing on the Flutter repo](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/41573) which describes your problem.

One of the given workarounds is to use a `HttpClient` and to set the `allowLegacyUnsafeRenegotiation` property to `true`

```
void main() async {
  final context = SecurityContext.defaultContext;
  context.allowLegacyUnsafeRenegotiation = true;
  final httpClient = HttpClient(context: context);
  final client = IOClient(httpClient);

  await client.get(Uri.parse('https://your_uri.net'));
}
```

This solution will only work on mobile though, the `http` package should not be used in Web mode.

Comment: `allowLegacyUnsafeRenegotiation` can't use. `The setter 'allowLegacyUnsafeRenegotiation' isn't defined for the type 'SecurityContext'`

Comment: You need at least Flutter 3.0.0 since it was updated in Dart 2.17 https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#dartio-2

Comment: Did not worked for me ((